# Jquery : Select last visible direct child

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="menu-items-wrapper" style="width: 547px;">
   <div class="one" style="height: 134px;">
   <div class="two" style="display:none;height: 134px;">
   <div class="other" style="height: 134px;">
   <div class="new" style="display: none; height: 134px;"></div>
</div>
```

I wish to get the last visible direct child from the html above. Please note that every child div has even more html in it so thats why I want the direct child.

What I have at the moment

```
  jQuery(".menu-items-wrapper > div").find(":visible:last-child").css("border-right","0px");
```

or

```
  jQuery(".menu-items-wrapper > div").find(":visible:last").css("border-right","0px");
```

But I cannot get the last direct child to have no border. Can anyone help

forgot to mention that i have that div like 12 times in the page and want to apply it to all occurences. at the moment its only working on the last item

Answer (score 10):

`.find()` looks for children within the set of elements given, which does not yield any elements here, because the set it is executed on is the lowest level of elements in the DOM.

You need to apply `:visible:last` immediately to the `div` selector:

```
$(".menu-items-wrapper > div:visible:last").css("border-right","0px");​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p8s5Q/)

For `.find()` you'd have to run it on the parent node:

```
$(".menu-items-wrapper").find("div:visible:last")
```

or just

```
$(".menu-items-wrapper").find(":visible:last")
```

---

**Edit**

To account for your addition in comments. In a scenario where there are several `menu-items-wrapper` elements, `:last` cannot be used in this manner, as it always selects the last element in the set. On the other hand `:last-child` would have worked if you always wanted the last element in each container, but this is of course not the case since the last child might not be the last *visible* child.

For that scenario, you'd have to iterate through the containers:

```
$(".menu-items-wrapper").each(function() {
    $('div:visible:last', this).css("border-right","0px");
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExTed/)

Comment: forgot to mention that i have that div like 12 times in the page and want to apply it to all occurences. at the moment its only working on the last item

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery('.menu-items-wrapper').children('div:visible:last').css(borderRight: '0px');`